Learning how to implement secure boot on an embedded system
I would like to learn how to implement secure boot on a device. I have a raspberry pi 2, and 3. I can get any board if it is required.
I have been working with embedded systems and embedded linux.
What I find our there are general talks about secure boot and what it is good and essential. I have not been successful at find a project to get hands-on experience.
What I would need is a suggestion and link to resources on how to implement a secure boot mechanism. I hope someone here can help me find a good resource.
I use linux but have access to Windows as well. I have been desperately looking for anything good.

You could use LUKs which will encrypt your disk and allow for secure booting, but the issue is that you have to store the key somewhere that is accessible to the boot process. This is the main weakness of LUKs.
You can use a Hardware Security Module (HSM) for this though. The Zymkey is such a module, but you really need a RPi 4 or 5 for that. Using that module, and the software for it, you can use LUKs to safely encrypt your boot disk, and the key is stored in the hardware, which the Pi then uses to decrypt the disk before booting it.
There's also Bootware which can also provide things like A/B partitioning for resilient updates, etc.
dg
